# Querying data from two different contexts using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two model classes which stores asset info as follow inside two different tables , which exists inside two different databases :-

```
Public class Resource {//from first databsee
Public String Name {set; get;}
Public Long RESOURCEID {set; get;}
//code goes here
}

Public class Technology {//from second database
Public String Tag {set; get;}
Public Long IT360ID {set; get;} // this contains the ResoruceID from the first table
//code goes here
}
```

Currently inside my search action method , which should search the data from the two databases I have the following:-

```
public IQueryable<Technology> AdvanceSearch(NameAdvanceSearch nas) 
        {

                var relatedresources = entities.Resources
                 .Where
                 (a =>

                 (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nas.name)
                     ||
                     (nas.nameselection == "contain" && a.RESOURCENAME.ToLower().Contains(nas.name.ToLower().Trim()))

                 ).Select(a => a.RESOURCEID).ToList();


                var technology = tms.Technologies.Where(a => 
((relatedresourcess.Contains(a.IT360ID.Value)) && ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(nas.tag) ||
                  nas.tagselection == "contain" && a.Tag.ToLower().Contains(nas.tag))
                    )).OrderBy(a=>a.TechnologyType.Name).ThenBy(a2=>a2.PartialTag);
                return technology;
```

So in the first query I am selecting all the IDs which match the entered name, and on the second query I will search based on the Tag + that have their IDs in the list return from the first query.
Currently my approach is working well , but I am afraid that my approach is not extensible , as the more I have data the more I will be processing and comparing data on the server instead of doing this inside the database. 
so what are the approaches I can follow to join the two tables inside the database server and retrieve the related records ?
Thanks

Comment: I've used views and then imported the view into my model. The other alternative is to use EF function import - here you would do all the processing in a stored procedure and then just call the function from your service layer.

Comment: but just a question what do u think about my current approach ? is good enough ? or i need to chnage the way i do the search . i mean by storing the related IDs in a list , then include this list in my second query?

Comment: and if i want to use view, then how i will be passing my search parameters from my asp.net mvc controller to my DB view?

Comment: From what I see, you seem to be hitting the db twice (run sql profiler to confirm). That isn't ideal in terms of performance. You would want to have one query sent to the db. Your approach seems like something I would possibly do on the server side as well. But like you have alluded to, its best left for the db. If you use a view, you would then import it into your model and be able to query it as it would be a dbset. However, I recommend using the stored proc as this would be most efficient and easy enough to pass parameters to: [link](http://rationalgeek.com/blog/function-imports/).